# How do you set default engine for the Schema Builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How can you set a default engine when using migrations (Schema Builder)? I recently got place on a shared hosting and their default MySQL engine is MyISAM. Instead of having to rewrite all my migration files to include `$table->engine = 'InnoDB'` I'm wondering if you can set this as default.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is,the docs http://laravel.com/docs/schema#storage-engines. Can't find any other mentioning of db engine in the docs.

You would expect it to be possible in app/config/database.php

Answer (score 4):

I manage to do it. I'm using Laravel 5.5. In the `config/database.php`:

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        ...
        'engine' => env('DB_ENGINE', null)
    ],
```

As you may know this will fetch the `DB_ENGINE` var from en `.env` file.
So in that file I setted like this:

```
DB_ENGINE=MyISAM
```

It will work if you set the var to `InnoDB` also.

Comment: I can confirm this still works on Laravel 8. This should be the correct answer, IMO. Thanks!

Comment: This should be marked as the best answer.